# Слитно, дефис или врозь?

Tags: орфография, дефис, слитно, раздельно

Итак, вопрос: как пишется слово «чат(-)рулетка»? Слитно, врозь или с дефисом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из рекламной статьи: *Чат рулетка – что это такое*?

И таких вариантов в Интернете много. Но это же **неправильно**, слово пишется через дефис. Но его нет в словаре, так что проверить нельзя.

А что есть? Орфографический словарь: ***ЧАТ***, -а (общение в Интернете)

Тогда почему мы выбираем **дефисную форму**?

**Раздельно** слово писаться не может, правила допускает раздельное написание для некоторых тематических групп (родовые и видовые названия,собственные и нарицательные имена, несколько исключений), слово ***чат*** туда не попадает. Такой "английский" вариант письма в русском языке пока еще  **не нормируется**, хотя на практике такие слова встречаются.

**Слитно** сложное слово тоже писаться не может. Даже если считать *чат* иноязычным элементом, оно все равно будет писаться через дефис, так как имеет явное определительное значение, то есть является приложением, а не образует новое слово (сравнить: *гала-концерт, арт-кафе*).

Итак, правильно: ***чат-рулетка.***

Раздельное же написание следует считать авторской (ненормированной) орфографией.

Answer (score 2):

Через дефис: чат-рулетка.

Через дефис пишутся следующие существительные и их сочетания:

1. сочетания с однословными приложениями (город-герой, рыба-попугай, дом-новостройка, студент-медик, старик-отец, красавица-дочка, трудяга-следователь);
2. сочетания с приложениями, в которых первая часть представляет собой несклоняемое существительное (кафе-автомат, каноэ-одиночка, пальто-пелерина);
3. сложные слова с несклоняемой первой частью, выраженной существительным в именительном падеже ед. ч., имеющим окончание (горе-охотник, эхо-импульс);
4. сложные слова с несклоняемой первой частью, выраженной существительным в именительном падеже ед. ч. без окончания или с нулевым окончанием (адрес-календарь, бизнес-класс, допинг-контроль, онлайн-опрос, пиар-акция)

Подробнее (справочник Лопатина): http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=63#pp63

Comment: А разве слово "чат" не склоняется? (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82)

Comment: Несклоняемое существительное в первой части.

Comment: Но ведь «чат» склоняемое слово!

Comment: Добавил всю сопутствующую информацию в ответ, чтобы всем было понятнее. Ссылку на справочник Лопатина оставил.